# Unmarshal XML with CDATA with GOLANG

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I trying to Unmarshal an XML file with CDATA fields in it. First I build a struct voor the XML file. Below is a shorten view. A have added the chardata tag in the struct.

```
type Ad struct {
    XMLName xml.Name                `xml:"ad"`
    Remark string                   `xml:"remark,chardata"`
}
```

But when I perform the xml.Unmarshal action I get the remark string back. Only it contains stil the <![CDATA and ]]> tags in the string.

Is there a nice way (not strings.Replace) to remove these tags?

Comment: What happens when you remove the chardata option? I would expect the parser to deal with that without any hints.

Comment: I get exact the same result. So CDATA tag is still in the string.

Comment: Hi, can you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the field that holds the character data section without the enclosing XML element in the tag:

```
Remark string `xml:",chardata"`
```

Your code would probably need to look something like this:

```
type Ad struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"ad"`
    Remark struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"remark"`
        Value string `xml:",chardata"`
    }
}

func main() {
    in := "<ad><remark><![CDATA[some stuff]]></remark></ad>"
    var ad Ad
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(in), &ad)
    fmt.Printf("remark: %s", ad.Remark.Value)
}
```

Can be tested here: https://play.golang.org/p/40MNzbbjKAp

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i tried but the CDATA is still in the string.

Comment: Are you getting the CDATA string running my example? I ran it and verified it's not present. If you are still having issues while working in your code base, it would be interesting to see an example of the XML. Can you add it to your question?